# How to get the colours I want with Leaflet.AwesomeMarkers?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to have the icon colour using awesome markers change depending on individual properties within each marker details, however they all are red instead of some being red and some being green.

Is anyone able to see the issue here? is it possible to have the same type have a different colour?

Ive added the sample below, the geojson I have set the icon colour in there, but all icons are red as you should be able to see?

Thanks

```js
 var map = L.map('map').setView([54.0, -3.4], 6);
 L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
  maxZoom: 18,
  id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
  accessToken: 'x'
 }).addTo(map);

    var geo_data = [
            {'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'name': 'A', 'popupContent': 'A', 'type': 'Showroom', 'icon': 'fa-home', 'color': '#d53f3a'
                }, 'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [
                        -2.2671,
                        57.139383
                    ]
                }
            },
            {'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'name': 'B', 'popupContent': 'B', 'type': 'Showroom', 'icon': 'fa-home', 'color': '#d53f3a'
                }, 'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [
                        0.4549,
                        51.611151
                    ]
                }
            },
            {'type': 'Feature', 'properties': {'name': 'C', 'popupContent': 'C', 'type': 'Showroom', 'icon': 'fa-home', 'color': '#47a447'
                }, 'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [
                        0.060676,
                        51.531023
                    ]
                }
            },
        ]
 
 
var Showroom = L.geoJSON(geo_data, {
    filter: function(feature, layer) {
        if (feature.geometry.coordinates != "None") {
            return feature.properties.type === "Showroom";
        }
    },
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.marker(latlng, {
            icon: L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({
                icon: feature.properties.icon, 
                markerColor: feature.properties.color, 
                prefix: 'fa', 
                iconColor: 'white'
            }
            )}
        );
    },
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup('<h3>'+feature.properties.popupContent+'</h3>');
        }
    });

    var overlayLayers= {  
        "Showroom": Showroom,
    };

    map.addLayer(Showroom)

    L.control.layers(null,overlayLayers).addTo(map);
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
        crossorigin=""/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Leaflet.awesome-markers/2.0.2/leaflet.awesome-markers.css" 
        integrity="sha256-EFpFyBbuttUJtoocYzsBnERPWee2JYz4cn5nkUBjW0A=" 
        crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css">
    </head>
<body>


<div id="map" style="height:700px;"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
 integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
 crossorigin="">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Leaflet.awesome-markers/2.0.2/leaflet.awesome-markers.min.js" 
 integrity="sha256-IqiRR5X1QtAdcq5lG4vBB1/WxwrRCkkjno4pfvWyag0=" 
 crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was just doing this in R yesterday - and leaflet was only taking very specific colors. So red, green and blue worked but not white or custom hex colors. Try that?

Comment: what about use this plugin isntead ? https://github.com/ilyankou/Leaflet.IconMaterial

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leaflet.AwesomeMarkers has a **limited** selection of available colours. Quoting from [its readme](https://github.com/lvoogdt/Leaflet.awesome-markers):

> `markerColor`     Color of the marker
>   Default `blue`
>   Possible vaules: `red`, `darkred`, `orange`, `green`, `darkgreen`, `blue`, `purple`, `darkpurple`, `cadetblue`

This is reinforced by the fact that AwesomeMarkers uses part of a [static image](https://github.com/lvoogdt/Leaflet.awesome-markers/blob/2.0/develop/dist/images/markers-matte.png) for the markers, and that image has only that limited selection of colours:

[image: ![](https://github.com/lvoogdt/Leaflet.awesome-markers/blob/2.0/develop/dist/images/markers-matte.png)]

Compare with the `iconColor` option, which can take any value. Quoting again, emphasis mine:

> `iconColor`   Color of the icon
>   Default `white`
>   Possible values: `white`, `black` or **css code (hex, rgba etc)**

You should consider [other marker plugins](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#markers--renderers), keeping the colours inside the selection available for AwesomeMarkers, or providing your own marker images.

Comment: thanks I just swapped to colour names and its all working as expected

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough I was also just poking around in dev console looking for a way to set the marker color to something other, at the same time I came across this thread, and I uncovered a **slightly different "static image"** (see below) as the one in the accepted answer, even though the Leaflet.awesome-markers Github notes do only mentions the colors as per the accepted answer.

[image: static image]

**This made me suspect there are other color names we can utilise** and digging a little further I took a peak at [leaflet.awesome-markers.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Leaflet.awesome-markers/2.0.2/leaflet.awesome-markers.css) which indeed listed various other color options: **lightgrey, pink, white, black** etc e.g. `markerColor: 'lightgray'`

```
/* Colors */
.awesome-marker-icon-red {
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.awesome-marker-icon-darkred {
  background-position: -180px 0;
}

.awesome-marker-icon-lightred {
  background-position: -360px 0;
}

.awesome-marker-icon-orange {
  background-position: -36px 0;
}

.awesome-marker-icon-beige {
  background-position: -396px 0;
}

.awesome-marker-icon-green {
  background-position: -72px 0;
}

.awesome-marker-icon-darkgreen {
  background-position: -252px 0;
}

.awesome-marker-icon-lightgreen {
  background-position: -432px 0;
}

.awesome-marker-icon-blue {
  background-position: -108px 0;
}

.awesome-marker-icon-darkblue {
  background-position: -216px 0;
}

.awesome-marker-icon-lightblue {
  background-position: -468px 0;
}

.awesome-marker-icon-purple {
  background-position: -144px 0;
}

.awesome-marker-icon-darkpurple {
  background-position: -288px 0;
}

.awesome-marker-icon-pink {
  background-position: -504px 0;
}

.awesome-marker-icon-cadetblue {
  background-position: -324px 0;
}

.awesome-marker-icon-white {
  background-position: -574px 0;
}

.awesome-marker-icon-gray {
  background-position: -648px 0;
}

.awesome-marker-icon-lightgray {
  background-position: -612px 0;
}

.awesome-marker-icon-black {
  background-position: -682px 0;
}
```

​

> So **these do appear to be addition default colours we can use** with
>   version **2.0.2** or leaflet.awesome-markers even though they do not
>   appear to be documented.
>   ​
>   ​​

​
As a side note I've also noticed that there is **another awesome-markers option** called '**extraClasses**' as specified in the documentation as follows:

```
extraClasses    Additional classes in the created tag   ''  'fa-rotate90 myclass' eller other custom configuration
```

So I've tried to create my own **.myclass** and added some `opacity: 0.4;` setting but **unfortunately using `extraClasses: myclass` this did not seem to work for me**. Not entirely sure what 'extraClasses' is exactly for, unless it's somehow specific to fontawesome styles or something. Perhaps someone else can elaborate on this in case it allows us to tweak the marker colour/appearance even further.

​​

**UPDATE:**

Further to my provided solution I did some more digging concerning the `extraClasses: myclass` which wasn't working for me initially, the reason being a bug with the minified version of the included JS file ([github/lvoogdt/Leaflet.awesome-markers/issues/92](https://github.com/lvoogdt/Leaflet.awesome-markers/issues/92)) which I happened to be using. Reverting to the **leaflet.awesome-markers.js** instead of leaflet.awesome-markers.min.js did manage to get **myclass** to now show up but unfortunately it was as I suspected on the fontawsome **< i >** tag and not the marker itself as you can see here:

```
<div class="awesome-marker-icon-lightgray awesome-marker leaflet-zoom-animated leaflet-interactive" tabindex="0" style="margin-left: -17px; margin-top: -42px; width: 35px; height: 45px; transform: translate3d(84px, -29px, 0px); z-index: -29;">
    <i class="myclass fa fa-circle  icon-white"></i>
</div>
```

In my particular case I decided to style the **lightgrey** marker by adding some styling to class **.awesome-marker-icon-lightgray** which is targeting the automatically assigned class for markers I styled with the new **lightgrey** color `markerColor: 'lightgray'` and adding `opacity: 0.4;` to **.awesome-marker-icon-lightgray** did the trick for me as it "greyed out" the lightgrey marker (if that makes sense) which is the effect I was after, indicating an inactive marker on my map.

​
Hope this helps anyone else who is struggling to style their Leaflet.AwesomeMarkers and doesn't fancy trying the alternative Material icons mention in a comment further up on this thread.
​​

​

​
**ALTERNATIVES**:

Create your own awsome icons using this simple to follow guide: [Create custom map marker icon with Leaflet](https://www.geoapify.com/create-custom-map-marker-icon/)

or use these simple, scalable SVG map markers with any Font Awesome icon by George MacKerron [github.com/jawj/MapMarkerAwesome](https://github.com/jawj/MapMarkerAwesome)